# How to make parent div not passing click to child div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent `<div />` that covers the whole page. Within this parent `<div />` I am having a smaller child `<div />`. I do not want the child `<div />` to be clickable, when the parent `<div />` overlays the child `.

```js
function parentFunction(event) {
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}

function childFunction() {
  alert("CHILD");
}
```

```css
    
.child {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    filter: blur(2px);
    display: flex;
    justifc-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div
      onclick="parentFunction(event)"
      class="parent">
      <div
          onclick="childFunction()"
          class="child">
          Child
      </div>
  </div>
</body>

Stop propagation:
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
```

Comment: The *parent* doesn't propagate events to the *child*.  The child is being clicked on and may or may not propagage to the parent.  If you just remove the `onclick="childFunction()"` entirely then nothing will happen when clicking on the child in this case.  Though I suspect the real problem you're trying to solve may not be accurately represented here.

Comment: @David Let me clarify: I cannot remove the function from the child `<div />`. What I want: When there is a prent overlaying the child, I do not want the child(s) to be clickable. The click should be captured on the level of the parent div.

Comment: the _parent_ cannot overlap the child. what the parent could do is to add another transparent child on the top. this new child will swallow those click events. Note that if you can change the CSS then you could add `pointer-events: none` for the first child and then you won't need anything else (but keyboard events and focus will still be possible)

Comment: `The click should be captured on the level of the parent div.` you then need to listen to the event on the parent in the capture phase. Or prevent any pointer events at the level of the parent using css.

Comment: How can the parent "overlay" the child - the child is inside the parent.  It's really unclear what the issue is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that would likely answer your need.

When you click on the Parent, which holds a child inside, it will tell you which element was clicked. Then you can *if* yourself into the destination/solution you require in the functionality.

```js
document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("click", parentFunction)
function parentFunction(e) {
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked && e.target == document.querySelector(".child")) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("EXIT")
    return;
  }
  console.log("PARENT says target is: ", e.target)
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justifc-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
}
    
.child {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    filter: blur(2px);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
cursor:pointer;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div
      class="parent">
      <div
          class="child">
          Child
      </div>
  </div>
</body>

Stop propagation:
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was previously stated the propagation goes from child to parent and not the other way around.

Possibilities you have:

- add the style pointer-events: none to the child div

or

- in the childFunction() check if the parent div exists and if so just return;

Answer (score 0):

It is on the other way around, when you click on the `child` you don't want the event to be propagated to the parent which is overlapping it, so it should be instead:

```js
function parentFunction(event) {
  console.log("PARENT");
}

function childFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  console.log("CHILD");
}
```

```css
.child {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  filter: blur(2px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div onclick="parentFunction(event)" class="parent">
    <div onclick="childFunction()" class="child">
      Child
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

Stop propagation:
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
```